# IE7 align text next to a button in a table cell

Tags: html, css, web, internet-explorer-7

I have this simple table where the last row displays a text next to an image button. This works well in other browser except IE7.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Some header</td>
      <td>Some other header</td>
    </tr>            
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="infoRow">Info:
      <input type="image" class="infoButton" src="Images/down_arrow.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

From CSS file:

```
.infoButton
{
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.infoRow
{
   text-align: right;
}
```

IE7 displays the text all the way to the right in the table cell and the image button is under it and also aligned to the right. I want to display the "Info:" text left of the image button, which works fine in other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you just remove the float you'll be fine.

Comment: That worked! Thx. But now the text is not vertically centered to next to the image button. I have tried "vertical-align:top" which puts the text in vertical center of the image. Works in Chrome but not in IE. Damn

Comment: @OliverNilsen, take a look at [this](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

Comment: I already tried this. This work perfectly as long as there is text in a table cell. But as soon I add an image button, the text is pushed further down while the image stays centered in the cell. I somehow need to "pull" the text up so it is centered left of the image.

Comment: Have you tried `vertical-align: middle` on the `input` as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `style="vertical-align:middle;"` to the input (and remove the `float`) this should work in IE.

I've tried this in all versions of IE and ever quirks and it works so I'm not sure why it wouldn't for you see below for code:

style:
`.infoButton {vertical-align:middle;padding:0;margin-left:20px;}
label {vertical-align:middle;}
.infoRow{text-align:right;}`

html:
`<td class="infoRow" valign="middle"><label>Info:</label><input type="image" class="infoButton" src="Images/down_arrow.png" /></td>`

Comment: My text is still not centered to the left of the image.

Comment: hmmm, it worked fine for me in IE7, is there a reason why you've used a colspan="2"? If you place the text and the image in separate `<td>` and `valign="middle"` them then it'll work. e.g `<td class="infoRow" valign="middle">Info:</td> 
      <td valign="middle"><input type="image" class="infoButton" src="Images/down_arrow.png" /></td>`

Comment: I already have a table with several rows. The last row is where I want to put an "Info" label and a little image: 27px x 27px. And I want all this to be in one row where everything is right-justified and the Info label is centered to the left the image. Sounds simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I've added to my answer above - not sure why this won't work for you.

Comment: This just doesn't work for me. As I said, the text is placed at the left bottom of the image. I perfectly understand the code, but it just doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the text on the left and the button on the right in my IE7.

You could try adding a style of "white-space:nowrap" onto the td.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to put a your info text in label tag`<label>info<label/>` this will work for IE7

Comment: I did try this. Works fine in Chrome. But not i IE. Jesus I hate IE.